# How to Identify NFT(ETC 721 Token) transfers on Ethereum Blockchain?

Tags: transactions, etherscan, nft

I am collecting data to study NFT transaction history. I want to comb through the Etherium blockchain and record all NFT Mint and transfer events.

I am at a loss how to identify from a transaction that it belongs to an NFT.

Answer (score 1):

NFTs (ERC721s) have token IDs: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1711075cf17b4c1716038b7cc53f222fa259a5beb33ee9baa51e764ab79cf2b2

ERC20s do not: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe9980abbd41863aea2e2532e9a069adc1ac7f8ffd05acb5a4a1d4cb51e7c6541